# How do I use my front facing camera on my Galaxy S?

Tags: camera, front-camera, webcam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My Samsung Galaxy S front-facing camera doesn't work in camera app, Gtalk or Skype — How can I use it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1805/my-samsung-galaxy-s-front-facing-camera-doesnt-work-in-camera-app-gtalk-or-sky)

It gives me the options of: single shot, beauty, smile shot, contiuous, panorama, vintage, add me, action shot, and cartoon. I can not find a way to use it. HELP???

Answer (score 1):

there is an button [image]

click it to change.

Answer (score 0):

Which camera application are you using?
If you use the stock camera, unfortunately for Samsung Galaxy S there's no such button or option to toggle between front/back camera, the front lens is used only for video chat. Maybe you should try other camera app on market or wait for the next update of the stock camera app (hopefully)