# How do I get back to the regular camera?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, camera, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I hit something by accident and now whenever I use the camera app it's using the front facing camera evey time.

How do I switch it back?

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17549/how-do-i-use-my-front-facing-camera-on-my-galaxy-s/17552#17552

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the camera app and press the button that looks like a camera with a circular arrow under it.

[image]

(original picture from [this article about ICS on thetechlabs.com](http://www.thetechlabs.com/tech-news/android-ice-cream-sandwich/))