# Does my galaxy s have a front facing camera or is it the just the light censor?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

it doesn't have a self shot option.
i got it from uscellular
model number is SCH-I500

Comment: Related question that was asked previously: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1805/my-samsung-galaxy-s-front-facing-camera-doesnt-work-in-camera-app-gtalk-or-sky?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

According to [gsmarena.com](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_fascinate-3492.php), your device (Samsung Fascinate SCH-I500) does **not** have either a **secondary camera** (front camera):

> ## **Camera**
>
> **Primary**    5 MP, 2592 x 1944 pixels, autofocus, LED flash
>
> **Secondary**    No

It is most likely a **proximity sensor** (which can double as a **light sensor**):

> ## **Features**
>
> **Sensors**    Accelerometer, proximity, compass